# Small Black color Square box appears on the Google Chrome web browser

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome

I'm using the wordpress site in which i have the plugin for posting the enquiry. I have installed the plugin called really-simple-captcha.

**In the enquiry plugin the there is a text area field for describing the messages.**

**when I view my site on google chrome browser a "small black color square box" appears on the web page and also this "small black color square box" appears on different locations on all other pages.**

but this there is no black square on the web page when i view on the other browsers like Mozilla Firefox, Internet Explorer, Opera Browser.

This black color square box is affecting the look and feel of my web page.
Could any one help to find the solution for this problem.

thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: get an Inspect element on Chrome on this element and look what is this and make a copy of that element codes and update your answer.

Comment: Show code and if possible then post live link also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem , In the CSS of the website, use CTRL + F to find

-webkit-resizer. Remove the entire style and your problem should dissapear.

Example :

```
-webkit-resizer {

background-color:#666;     //REMOVE THIS SECTION OF CODE FROM YOUR CSS        
cursor:pointer;}
```

Comment: My answer is based on editing the inspector console and it worked, Please let me know if you have any luck.

Comment: Thanks Steve, It working fine. Could you please tell me the cause of this error. It helps me to understand the cause of this error.

Comment: As for the actual cause I cannot explain Im sorry, I don't actually know. My guess would be something to do with the wordpress theme and the way it generates its styles. The way I found the error was I Inspected the element in the near area which was <aside id="contentbottom"> and checked all the styles for it, finally I found the color property that looked very similar and I removed it and It went away.

Comment: I might add that the -webkit-resizer is the resizing grab for users to change the size of the text box.  I believe it is your message box that was causing the issue, but it still should not apply extra styling on its own, I hope this helps. You may want to make it so users cannot change the size of this box with their mouse unless that is your intention.